# Valgrind memory debugging for nodejs using child process

Tags: node.js, debugging, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to debug a nodejs script which has dependencies on native bindings. That script also involves forking a child process. I am using `valgrind` to debug the memory issues with following options:

```
valgrind --leak-check=summary --show-leak-kinds=all --trace-children=yes --verbose  node app.js
```

It only works if I set `--trace-children=no`, otherwise always failed.

I created following sample script to test the scenario and it seems `valgrind` does not work debugging child process running in node.

```
// main.js
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('./worker');

child.on('message', function(m) {
  // Receive results from child process
  console.log('received: ' + m);
});

// Send child process some work
child.send('Please up-case this string');
```

and

```
worker.js
process.on('message', function(m) {
  // Do work  (in this case just up-case the string
  m = m.toUpperCase();

  // Pass results back to parent process
  process.send(m.toUpperCase(m));
});
```

And `valgrind` always failed with following error:

```
==10401== execve(0x1048a3150(/bin/bash), 0x1048a3638, 0x1048a3658) failed, errno 2
==10401== EXEC FAILED: I can't recover from execve() failing, so I'm dying.
==10401== Add more stringent tests in PRE(sys_execve), or work out how to recover.
```

Comment: Just noticed that you use `child_process` or not `--trace-children=yes` always failed with same error.

Comment: You might need to use the option --smc-check=none|stack|all|all-non-file [all-non-file]. Try also with a simpler tool (--tool=none). Then put some tracing (e.g. -v -v -v -d -d -d --trace-syscalls=yes). And report a bug on valgrind bugzilla

Comment: I noticed further that this issues only happen to `macOS`, I tried on `Ubuntu` and its working pretty fine on it.

Comment: Ok, good news that it works on Ubuntu. Would be nice to report a bug in valgrind bugzilla for MacOS.